# Request with google chrome api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing an extension for google chrome, where I hear the commands CTRL + SHIFT + 1 and CTRL + SHIFT + 2 and I store the text of the mouse selection. When the user hits CTRL + SHIFT + 3 or CTRL + SHIFT + 4 I would like to check if the element is editable, input or textarea and insert the text stored in a Storage Location.

The problem is that I can only access the window elements through my background.js where I create the LocalStorage with texts, but I can not access this data through my content_script.js.

I think the most correct way to solve it is every time the user presses CTRL + SHIFT + 1 and CTRL + SHIFT + 2, the background.js send a message to the content_script.js with the data necessary to store the LocalStorage in content_script.js.

How can I do this with the api Google Chrome Extension? I found nothing to help me yet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is sharing storage with your content script, you should look into [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). It's a storage area that is accessible both to your background and content scripts.

The transition from `localStorage` is not painless though, since the API is asynchronous.

As for messaging, well, use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). The API to send a message **to content scripts** is [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage). Your question it too vague for more detailed advice.